# Docker compose - pymongo - server_type:unknown

Tags: python, docker, pymongo

Quero colocar minha aplicação em DOIS containers docker. Um com o mongodb (imagem oficial) e outro com a imagem do ubuntu, que roda uma série de scripts para povoar o banco de dados.

Não estou conseguindo realizar a conexão com o mongodb no outro container.Tudo sobe normalmente, mas na hora de realizar a conexão, aparece o seguinte erro:

> pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: mongodb:27017: [Errno -2] Name or service not known, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 5fc91e204a30bae1451e3afd, topology_type: Single, servers: [<ServerDescription ('mongodb', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=AutoReconnect('mongodb:27017: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')

Segue meu docker-compose.yml

```yml
version: '3.1'

services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: user
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: *****
    
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - /mnt/docker_volumes/
  
  CNPJ_to_mongo:
        build: .
        container_name: "cnpj_to_mongo"
        image: python:latest
        environment:
            - NODE_ENV=development
            - FOO=bar
        volumes:
            - /mnt/docker_volumes/
        
        links:
            - mongodb
        depends_on:
            - mongodb
```

E o Dockerfile do app:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

MAINTAINER Bruno Prado <brunocpradom@gmail.com>

CMD echo Start configuration of the workspace!

WORKDIR /home/
COPY ./ /home/

VOLUME /mnt/docker_volume/

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3 &&\
    apt-get install -y python3-pip &&\
    pip3 install pymongo &&\
    python3 teste.py
```

O trecho do script que faz a conexão com o banco de dados

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient(host='mongodb',port=27017,username = 'user',
                    password = '*****')
```

Documentação do docker:

> Each container for a service joins the default network and is both reachable by other containers
> on that network, and discoverable by then at a hostname identical to the container name.

Coloquei no host o nome do container mongodb, a porta e a senha. Onde foi que errei?

Comment: Cara, tenta mudar o seu código python pra o que está neste gist https://gist.github.com/jfbueno/984871fe4e1ab7023bf86b1a4f711f37. E, claro, faça a instalação da lib retry pelo pip no seu Dockerfile. Se funcionar, avise aqui que eu escrevo uma resposta explicando.

Comment: Tentei do jeito que você falou . E deu o mesmo erro..

Comment: Esqueci de um detalhe, seu dockerfile precisa ficar diferente. Veja lá no gist https://gist.github.com/jfbueno/984871fe4e1ab7023bf86b1a4f711f37

Comment: Agora tudo corre absolutamente normal. Mas quando entro no container do mongodb ele está vazio. O script rodou mas não fez a inserção.... 
Já consegui povoar um container mongodb do localhost, mas de um outro container tá difícil.